# Android: Rename Package in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, package

Is there a way to excecute the Eclipse command "Android Tools -> Rename Application Package" as a script from the shell?

I want to compile my Android application several times with different options (e.g. free and paid version) without doing some things manually.
It is important to do this automatically. All solutions like libraries won't help because several things have to be done by hand.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, the fastest way is to use keyboard shortcut (cmd+option+r on os x)

Comment: Good question, this would be very handy.
That said though, I've found the UI tool to be less than 100% perfect so I'm not sure I would use it as part of an automated build.

Comment: "All solutions like libraries won't help because several things have to be done by hand" -- what are these "several things"?

Comment: i thought you were supposed to do free/paid versions just by the version # i  the manifest

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You have to manually call `aapt` tool to package the compiled project, then call `aapt` again to add the classes, sign it with `jarsigner` and align it with `zipalign`. Normally, the Eclipse ADT plugin does the chain of build steps for you.

Example calls of the steps would be following.

1. Packaging the app with different package name:

   ```
   aapt package -f -M ./AndroidManifest.xml -S res/ \
       -I android.jar -F renamed_project.apk.unaligned \
       --rename-manifest-package "com.example.some_new_package" -v
   ```
2. Then add the classes:

   ```
   aapt add -f renamed_project.apk.unaligned classes.dex -v
   ```
3. Sign it:

   ```
   jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 \
       -keystore "some_keystore_file" \ 
       renamed_project.apk.unaligned "key_name"
   ```
4. Align it:

   ```
   zipalign -v 4 renamed_project.apk.unaligned renamed_project.apk
   ```

Some more information can be found for example [here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/08/22/building-android-application-bundles-apks-by-hand/).

Also you can do it more easily with `Ant`. [Here](http://www.evertrue.com/blog/2012/06/15/how-to-rename-package-name-using-ant-for-android/#.UTTgZ-tevzI) you can find some more information.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the solution. After renaming and adding classes.dex (step 1+2) the application has half the size than before. Installing on emulator throws a "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]" error.

Comment: I wrote just an example packaging. Your build will probably require adding some more parameters to the calls, e.g. project libraries.